# clearInterval function working mysteriously

Tags: javascript, function, order-of-execution

We all know that when a function on completion can return a value.
Now consider the following line of code

```
var t = setInterval(function() {
  console.log('hey hi hello now 2 seconds have passed down');
} ,2000);
clearInterval(t);
```

Now, `clearInterval()` takes the unique id returned by the `setInterval()` function as an argument and this will only be returned once the function has completely run. What happens in my code, is that before my `setInterval()` function runs, it gets cleared and this should not be possible as `setinterval()` will not return anything until its callback function has been called.

How is the `clearInterval()` function able to run before the `setinterval()` function?

Comment: _"as setinterval() will not return anything until its callback function has been called."_ What makes you think that?

Comment: Setinterval( ) function will be completed only when its callback function has been executed once that is what i assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is you call `setInterval` function at the first time in the first line of your code, it returns an **ID** for it.

This **ID** not related to the invoke of the function,  After that you tell the JS to remove this interval. so no thing will happen.

These are the steps that happens:

```
 // Step #1 
 var t = setInterval(
    // Step #3
    function () {console.log('hey hi hello now 2 seconds have passed down');}

  , 2000);
clearInterval(t);// Step #2
```

So the problem is that you clear the interval before the invoking of the function. but after the declaration.

`Wrong!`

1- Declare -> Clear -> Invoke

`Correct`

1- Declare -> Invoke -> Clear

As as **solution:**

call `clearInterval` inside `setInterval`.

***Like this:***

```js
var t = setInterval(function () {
    console.log('hey hi hello now 2 seconds have passed down');
    clearInterval(t);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I know this i  want to just know that how my clearInterval() function is being executed before my setInterval() function as it will only run when setInterval() function returns a value.

Comment: @HARSHBAJPAI check the new edition of my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

> `setinterval()` will not return anything until its callback function has been called

That's entirely not true. Set interval returns unique handle immediately, so you can remove interval even before first function run. The *callback* function, so the first parameter you pass to `setInterval` is not gonna return anything until it's run. But even after running, its return value is neveer assigned back to the variable hloding unique handle (in your case - `var t`).

`setInterval` puts piece of code to the bottom of the stack, so the rest of the code gets executed before it. Effectively, you clear interval before function is executed.

Comment: @HARSHBAJPAI and what precisely does the code from your comment have to do with anything related to the question?